# É correto utilizar a palavra "OK" nas outras línguas que não a inglesa?

Tags: significado, etimologia, tradução-inglês, origem-histórica, significado-em-contexto

É  correto utilizar a palavra "OK" nas outras linguas que nao a inglesa?
Muito utilizado de forma verbal em várias línguas

Comment: CIMend, por que estaria errado? Se vem de outra língua, é italizado ou, caso já tenha sido integrado na língua, escrever a forma aportuguesada.

Comment: Vale notar que "OK" já é dicionarizado no português, e.g.: https://dicionario.priberam.org/OK

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não, A palavra *OK* **não existe** no português e por isso não é correto usar ela. Você não pode usar *OK* em uma redação ou em um documento oficial. Salvo casos em que você precisa transcrever algo, como uma ação judicial ou um boletim de ocorrência. Nesse caso, você deve por entre aspas ou em itálico.

Gostaria de deixar um adendo a resposta, cuidado com o sinal de *OK*, ele foi incluído numa lista mundial de sinais de ódio, pois remete a um grupo extremista, inclusive o mesmo sinal é ofensivo em muitos países por conta da religião. No Brasil por exemplo, o sinal de *OK* remete a um grupo de fações em específico, muito cuidado se for usar ele.

Comment: Fontesj, a linguagem coloquial também é português: a língua portuguesa não se reduz às palavras que se podem usar num documento oficial. Por essa ordem ideias há um montão de palavras que "não existem no português"; só que existem porque nós as usamos. Não deves ter dificuldades em pensar em várias. Do mesmo modo, num documento oficial não se escreve "usar ela"; escreve-se "usá-la"; mas tu escreveste "usar ela" na tua resposta.

Comment: @Jacinto, eu já tinha lhe dito isso. Fontesj disse que se referia exclusivamente à linguagem formal; por isso que eu tinha lhe recomendado tornar o texto mais literal.

Comment: A palavra é de uso corrente e está inclusive dicionarizada ([no Priberam, por exemplo](https://dicionario.priberam.org/OK)), ou seja, ela foi adotada pelos usuários da língua portuguesa e, portanto, existe sim. Se desconsiderarmos todas as palavras que foram emprestadas de outros idiomas, vai sobrar pouca coisa.

Answer (score 3):

Resposta curta:

Sim, na **língua portuguesa** é correto.  A expressão já vem sendo usada no Brasil, de modo disseminado, há muitas décadas. Na língua falada seu uso é corriqueiro.  Na escrita formal, eu evitaria.

Quanto ao seu uso em "outras línguas", foge ao tópico "língua portuguesa".

Comment: Qual a origem da conjugação destas duas Letras : OK